# Fourier series and transform (epicycles)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous curve.

**1)** Is it true that one can find a sequence of numbers $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset (0,\infty)$ and some function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\times [a,b]\to\mathbb{R},\ \varphi\in C^{1}$ such that the sequence of curves:

$$\gamma_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C},\ \gamma_{n}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n r_k e^{i\varphi(k,t)}$$

converges uniformly to $\gamma$ on $[a,b]$? Moreover can we choose $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to be decreasing or strictly decreasing? Can we choose $\varphi (k,t)=2k\pi t$?

**2)** Is it true that there is a function $r:\mathbb{R}\to (0,\infty),\ r\in L^1 (\mathbb{R})$ such that $r(k)=r_k,\ \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ and

$$\gamma(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}r(x)e^{i2\pi x t} dx\ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

**Edited following the original post's edit**

($1$) For the first one, that's still not possible, consider the sawtooth function

$$s(t) = {1\over 2}-t, 0\le t\le 1.$$

Then a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous $L^1(\Bbb T)$ (i.e. periodic) functions is also continuous and periodic. However

$$\lim_{t\to 1-}s(t)=-{1\over 2}\quad \lim_{t\to 1+}s(t)={1\over 2}$$

so that the limiting function cannot be periodic. You may argue we don't start with a periodic function, $s(0)\ne s(1)$, however remember that $L^1$ functions are equal a.e., so that the series *has* to be the same as the a.e. equal function where we define it only on $[0,1)$ and extend by periodicity. But we know that Fourier series converge to ${1\over 2}(f(x^+)+f(x^-))$ around every point, so the limiting function would have value $0$ at $0$ and left-hand limit ${1\over 2}$, and so cannot be the continuous function, $s(t)$.

For the second part, the counterexample from before is no less true when you change it to "moreover can we" followed by the same hypotheses, i.e. you can still just consider $\gamma(t)\equiv 1$ and let $I$ be whatever you want. The uniqueness of Fourier series says that only the sequence

$$c_n=\begin{cases} 1 & n=0 \\ 0 & n\ne 0\end{cases}$$

converges to the constant function $1$ (even point-wise), among all sequences of linear combinations of the functions $\{e^{2\pi i n}\}_{n\in\Bbb Z}$, but your sequence $r_k$ is $0$ for $k=0$.

($2$) Clearly if this is so then

$$|\gamma(t)|=\left|\int_{\Bbb R}r(x)e^{2\pi i x}\,dx\right|\le \lVert r\rVert_1<\infty$$

so choose any $\gamma$ which is unbounded and that is a counterexample, eg. $\gamma(t)=t$ and $I=\Bbb R$.

Comment: I have edited my post. Thanks for your remarks!

Comment: @Bogdan and my edited response is now available.

Comment: This is strange. I found that any curve can be obtain by a number of epicycles. See this video for example:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVuU2YCwHjw

Comment: @Bogdan note that the very first paragraph to appear in that video includes the clause "periodic." You just asked for a general continuous curve, not a continuous **and** periodic curve. The difference is as stark as night and day.

Comment: Now I see... So it is true what I've written if we add periodicity?

Comment: @Bogdan even then, not necessarily since Fourier series can fail to converge even for continuous, periodic functions, however--if you're willing to admit $r_{n,k}$ rather than just $r_k$, then the answer is "yes, absolutely." And this is the content of Montgomery's *Early Fourier Analysis* Theorem 4.1